# Android Studio debug native code lldb server work infinity

Tags: java, android, c++

I have Android app which are writed use Java and C++/JNI code. My C++/JNI part work bad. I want to debug native code. 
I work in Android Studio. 
I did all step which take official site

[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html)

But when I start debug I see line

```
Starting LLDB server
```

And he does not finish. I wait 30 min but he does not finish.
What I must to do. Because I think this bug or I must to take some settings.

Comment: In debug console show red line:                                                     
Waiting for application to start debug server

Answer (score 1):

I found error. But I did not understand. When I test app from USB cable all work good. But when I want to test my app through wifi (I use Android Wifi ADB) LLDB Debug server start, but not attach to process.

If I debug java code use java debugger all work good.

Answer (score 0):

All output in debug console:

Connecting to org.temp.test
Waiting for application to start debug server
Waiting for application to come online: org.temp.test.test | org.temp.test
Connecting to org.temp.test

Now Launching Native Debug Session

Starting LLDB server: /data/data/org.temp.test/lldb/bin/start_lldb_server.sh /data/data/org.temp.test/lldb unix-abstract /data/data/org.temp.test/lldb/tmp platform-1524470360668.sock "lldb process:gdb-remote packets"